# onBackPressed not taking any action

Tags: android

I'm trying to Use the `onBackPressed` So the user can cancel the asynctask operation.  But when you press the back button on the device it doesn't do anything. My asynctask still runs and my progress dialog still shows. Can someone assist me and help me find out the problem.

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {    


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;        

     final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
     final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
     final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "content";      
     final String TAG_QUERY = "query";
     ProgressDialog pDialog;
     LoadAllData mTask; 

            JSONArray question = null;          
            android.widget.ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        

    questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

    mTask = new LoadAllData();

         mTask.execute();

        }


    @Override   
    protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
         super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);  

          HashMap<String, String> item = questionList.get(pos);

          Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, SingleListItem.class);
          i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT));
          i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT));
          i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER));
          startActivity(i);

            }     

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {              
        /** If user Pressed BackButton While Running Asynctask
            this will close the ASynctask.
         */
        if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
        {
            mTask.cancel(true);
        }          
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    /** If Activity is Destroyed While Running Asynctask
            this will close the ASynctask.   */

     if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
     {
        mTask.cancel(true);
      }  

        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     if (pDialog != null)
     {
         if(pDialog.isShowing())
         {
             pDialog.dismiss();
         }
            super.onPause();

      }  

    }

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();             
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://rxample.com";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {

                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                    //JSONArray Answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);


                    //JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(0);

                    //String Content = Answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);

                               questionList.add(map);

                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return TAG_QUESTION ;           

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.listelements,
                        new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject,});

                setListAdapter(adapter);                

        }       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem in work of your ProgressDialog. It is catching back-button-click while working in front. And you can't dismiss it because of `pDialog.setCancelable(false);`

Change cancelable on true `pDialog.setCancelable(`**true**`)` and set [OnCancelListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnCancelListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29) which will been called when dialog is become canceled.

Answer (score 0):

When you cancel an `AsyncTask`, it sets the cancelled flag. In the `doInBackground()` function you need to check `isCancelled()` to see if `cancel()` has been called. Also `onPostExecute()` is not called when the task is cancelled. Instead implement `onCancelled(Object)` to clean up anything you need to.

```
class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();             
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            Intent in = getIntent();
            String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
            String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
            String URL = "http://rxample.com";
            JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
            try {

                JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");
                //Stop looping on cancel
                for(int i = 0; i < questions.length()&&!isCancelled(); i++) {
                    JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                    //JSONArray Answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);


                    //JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(0);

                    //String Content = Answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                    map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
                    map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);

                    questionList.add(map);

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return TAG_QUESTION ;           

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                    R.layout.listelements,
                    new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT }, new int[] {
                    R.id.Subject,});

        setListAdapter(adapter);                

    }       

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(String result) {
        //Clean up
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask cancel() will not kill your async task. It just sets a boolean flag so isCancelled() on task object returns true so you can bail out from your long running doInBackground. I do believe that everything works as expected from your code above. If the task is cancelled onPostExecute won't run so your progress dialog would not be dismissed. It would invoke onCancelled() instead.